# Are MySQL databases with a MEMORY storage engine persisted to disk?

Tags: mysql, database, memory, disk, storage-engines

If MySQL databases with a MEMORY engine are *stored* in memory, does this mean that their contents are not persisted to disk? Or are they stored on HDD, but fully loaded into RAM on system power up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one file one disk that contains database **definition** but data never goes on disk. Data is lost when server shut down.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

When tables become overly larges you just get errors. However like any other memory usage it can be swapped... and then will use some disk.

Answer (score 1):

Contents are not persisted to disk, they are lost when You shut down server.
This is perfect table type for temporary data.

More here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html